# 'npm start' throws error related to package.json

Tags: reactjs, json, bash, npm

When I want to start my React application using 'npm start' I get the following error message from the terminal:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/louis/afrikalink/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/louis/afrikalink/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/louis/.npm/_logs/2023-03-27T22_20_04_933Z-debug-0.log
```

I didn't change anything in the package.json, I only wrote the js and css files.

```json
{
  "name": "afrikalink",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I didn't change anything in the package.json, I only wrote the js and css files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to run `npm start` outside the project

Open the terminal and navigate to the root of the project and run the command